# Webflow CMS + Leaflet + Filtres par distance

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, leaflet, webflow

I am currently working on a real estate website. I use leaflet to geolocalize the properties on a map.

here is the code that displays the markers on the map

`window.GeoComponents = {`

```
maps2d: [],
  init2d: function () {
    // Clean up existing maps, in case this is reinitializing
    window.GeoComponents.maps2d.forEach(function (map) {
      map.remove();
    });
    window.GeoComponents.maps2d = [];
    // Set up Leaflet for each [data-geo-map]
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-geo-map]')).forEach(function (mapEl) {
      const mapId = mapEl.getAttribute('data-geo-map');
      const map = L.map(mapEl);
      window.GeoComponents.maps2d.push(map);

      // Mise en place de la map
      L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution:
          '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
      }).addTo(map);

      // Mise en place des markers
      const allCoordinates = [];
      const markers = [];
      Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-geo-place="' + mapId + '"]')).forEach(function (
        placeEl
      ) {
        const coordinates = [
          placeEl.value.coordinates.latitude,
          placeEl.value.coordinates.longitude,
        ];
        allCoordinates.push(coordinates);
        const marker = L.marker(coordinates).addTo(map).bindPopup(placeEl.innerHTML);
        markers.push(marker);

        // Au clic, montre le marker et sa popup sur la map
        function clickPlace() {
          map.panTo(coordinates, {
            animate: true,
            duration: 0.5,
          });
          // Close other popups
          markers.forEach(function (otherMarker) {
            otherMarker.closePopup();
          });
          marker.openPopup();
        }
        placeEl.addEventListener('click', clickPlace);
        map.on('unload', function () {
          placeEl.removeEventListener('click', clickPlace);
        });
      });
      // Zoom to the markers added
      map.fitBounds(L.latLngBounds(allCoordinates));
    });
  },
};

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', window.GeoComponents.init2d);

window.fsAttributes = window.fsAttributes || [];
window.fsAttributes.push([
  'cmsfilter',
  (filterInstances) => {
    console.log('Filtres CMS Finsweet chargés avec succès');

    // The callback passes a `filterInstances` array with all the `CMSFilters` instances on the page.
    const [filterInstance] = filterInstances;

    // The `renderitems` event runs whenever the list renders items after filtering.
    filterInstance.listInstance.on('renderitems', (renderedItems) => {
      const itemsOnScreen = Array.from(renderedItems);
      if (itemsOnScreen.length === 0) {
        console.log('Nouveau filtrage');
        console.log('Pas de nouvelles annonces.');
        const MapOnScreen = document.querySelector('.annonces_map');

        // ajoute ici une fonction pour cacher la map lorsque les résultats sont vides.
      } else {
        console.log('Nouveau filtrage');
        console.log('Plusieurs annonces.');

        //Creation des latitudes/longitude selon les annonces
        const places = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-geo-place]'));
        places.forEach(function (el) {
          const elCoords = el
            .querySelector('[data-geo-coordinates]')
            .textContent.split(',')
            .map(Number);
          const value = {
            coordinates: {
              latitude: elCoords[0],
              longitude: elCoords[1],
            },
          };
          el.value = value;
          // Just for debug(?)
          el.setAttribute('data-geo-value', JSON.stringify(value));
        });
        //Chargement de la Map
        window.GeoComponents.init2d();
      }
    });
  },
]);
```

on my Webflow CMS I apply 3 attributes to my HTLM elements

A "data-geo-map = 2" to target the div that will contain the map

A "data-geo-place = 2" for the pop-up to display on the map

A "data-geo-coordinates=1" which contains the latitude and longitude to place the markers on the map.

My problem is that I would like to create a filter that filters according to a distance in KM from a selected city. And that makes a circle around this same property.

Example if I choose the city of LA with a radius of 20km around LA I want to display markers and real estate ads that are in the circle and not outside.

Here is the link of my site in reading only or you will be able to consult all the information.

Read-link : https://preview.webflow.com/preview/api-transaction-91d626df5379af052a1accc?utm_medium=preview_link&utm_source=designer&utm_content=api-transaction-91d626df5379af052a1accc&preview=d4913aafef21e15266b06c6d2f3e1769&pageId=63d8cea19751ec322a935af2&workflow=preview

I thank you in advance for helping me bring

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's all code i can provide it's a CMS Editor